# Why won't my JSON serialise?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In a Web API controller, I return a JSON encoded object, in fact a list of `Organization` objects, each with its own collection of `Branch` objects, again each with a list of `Person` objects.

I return it like this from the controller, as an `IHttpActionResult`:

```
return Ok(SerializeObject(orgs));
```

where:

```
protected virtual string SerializeObject(object source)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, SharedSettings.JsonSerializerSettings);
}
```

and

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings { get; } = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
};
```

I request it like:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync(resource, null);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    RaiseException(response, exMsg);
}
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TReturn>(content, SharedSettings.JsonSerializerSettings);
```

I don't use `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TReturn>()` because I want to be really sure I'm using the same Json serializer and its settings on both sides. The JSON returned looks fine, if you'll excuse a few lines for brevity:

```
[
    {
        "Branches": [
            {
                "People": [
                    {
                        "FullName": "Katie Darwin",
                        "BranchId": 2,
                        "OrgId": 2,
                        "Id": 18
                    }
                ],
                "Name": "Jolimont",
                "Phone": null,
                "OrgId": 2,
                "Id": 2
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Contoso, Ltd.",
        "Id": 2
    },
    {
        "Branches": [],
        "Name": "Trey Research",
        "Id": 11
    }
]
```

The exception I get on deserialisation is

> 'Error converting value "" " to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ApptEase.DataModels.Entities.Organization]'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 439200.

I have never experienced any such trouble with NewtonSoft JSON before, but maybe I'm only placed less demand on it. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

**BREAKING:** If I write that JSON string to a file, then read it with a small test program, it deserialises fine, with no explicit options. Being hopeful, I removed the options clause from the deserialize in the main program, but I still get the same error. I think I should start looking at a text encoding problem.

It might also be noted that the `Content-Length` header and the error position are equal: 439200.

Comment: What's at position 439200? Can you post the chunk?

Comment: @Juan a quick `json[439200]` check reveals a space, i.e. char 32, and that would seem to be a space after the overall ending ']'.

Comment: The error seems to suggest there is a problem with the JSON. What are you using to generate it? Here is another suggestion: get a JSON visualizer plugin for your browser and hit the service directly if possible. See if the parser cries.

Comment: You must be double-serializing your object on the server side along the lines of [Turn C# object to json string, how to handle double quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293208) and [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559179/).  [`OK<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Ok%60%601%28%60%600%29) should serialize for you.

Comment: @Juan, the parser doesn't cry, but only because the content returned is all double serialised JSON, i.e. all non-alpha-num elements are escaped. I'm not using anything to generate it, I leave that up to the `ApiController`, e.g. `return Ok(orgs)` where `orgs` is `List<Organization>`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid, and stupid to let myself be misled by so many varied and so incorrect examples. I had forgotten that one of the tenets of an `ApiController` is that it act more like a repository than a controller, with no HTTP crap anywhere. The controller in question now looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/Org")]
public class OrgController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Organization> Get()
    {
        Db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return Db.Organizations.ToList();
    }
}
```

And the object returned is obtained like this, with the `Content.ReadAsAsync<TReturn>()`.

```
public virtual async Task<TReturn> PostAsync<TReturn>(string resource)
{
    var exMsg = $"Post request failed to get resource: '{resource}' from '{Client.BaseAddress}'.";
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync(resource, null);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            RaiseException(response, exMsg);
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TReturn>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex.GetType() != typeof(RestClientException))
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I probably should be using custom `Response` objects, that can provide the caller more information, e.g. an exception caught, but raw like this is how it was designed to work and work like this it does.