# C# escapes double quote " symbol automatically with backslash

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am writing some website parser and analyzer.

And I am building a JSON object from parsed parameters.
For example a website has title
`Buy best phones from "NOKIA COMPANY LTD"`
As you can see title has double  quote symbol: `"`
So when I parse title, I get this:

`Buy best phones from \"NOKIA COMPANY LTD\" and call anyone`

Then I generate a JSON object which will be used by frontend developers.
I am using JSON newton soft library
like this =

```
 var obj = new 
    { 
      Title = parsedTitle, 
      H1 = "some h1"
    };
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);`

And as and out put I get not valid json, so frontend developers get an error.

Output JSON will be something like:

```
{
  "title": " Buy best phones from \\"
   NOKIA COMPANY LTD\\" and call anyone",
  "h1:: "some h1"
}
```

As you can see it is not valid JSON.
What do I do?

Comment: Are you viewing it [from the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5465923/11683)?

Comment: and how do you "parse the title" => show the code. in a web page source, it should be &quot; if any

Comment: how come single backslash gets converted to double backslash?

Comment: There are related Q&As here, for example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22293208/335858).

Comment: What is in `parsedTitle` and what is in `settings`? Please provide this information in a way so we can *exactly* reproduce *exactly* what your code is doing. A conversation description of the string isn't enough. It's also possible that your frontend developers are creating the problem on their end.